# Accessing Data Externally - Any tools?

Tags: data-export, database, tools

Bit of a back story...

We have a business requirement where out of a team of 50 people only 20 need actual SF licenses. The other 30 only need access to a very small portion of data and only need read only access.

The first solution was to run a scheduler and send a report to a shared location daily, which works but is really clunky...

My next thought was to develop a web app using an integration user profile but this would have to go through the companies security team and I am hoping there is a better solution out there...

So my question is with the requirement above, forgetting what I have said does anyone have a solution? The full SF licenses are too expensive for the minimal amount of data they need to see and considering they need to see read only data it doesn't make sense financially.

Anyone got any suggestions? Any cool tools floating around?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Force.com Sites, which is available for free with an Enterprise License. It allows you to create a Visualforce page that is publicly accessible so anybody with a link can visit it.

Of course, you could use some sort of token in the URL to restrict access to people outside the company.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites for more information.

Comment: Definitely a valid suggestion thank you. I guess my "perfeect solution" would be the same sort of thing but if there was a plug and play web app that required minimal config that we could host internally for security purposes that would be amazing.... but I feel like I am pushing it a little...